# Stata: Maximum number of consecutive occurrences of the same value across variables

Tags: stata

Observations in my dataset are players, and binary variables `temp1` up are equal to 1 if the player made a move, and equal to zero otherwise. 
I would like to to calculate the maximum number of consecutive moves per player.

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| simulation | playerlist | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | temp4 | temp5 | temp6 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|          1 |          1 |     0 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |
|          1 |          2 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     1 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

My idea was to generate auxiliary variables in a loop, which would count consecutive duplicates and then apply egen, rowmax():

```
+------------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| simulation | playerlist | aux1 | aux2 | aux3 | aux4 | aux5 | aux6 | _max |
+------------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|          1 |          1 |    0 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    0 |    0 |    3 |
|          1 |          2 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    2 |    2 |
+------------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I am struggling with introducing a local counter variable that would be incrementally increased by 1 if consecutive move is made, and would be reset to zero otherwise (the code below keeps auxiliary variables fixed..):

```
    quietly forval i = 1/42 { /*42 is max number of variables temp*/
    local j = 1 
    gen aux`i'=.    
    local j = `j'+1
    replace aux`i'= `j' if temp`i'!=0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tactical answer**

You can concatenate your `move*` variables into a single string and look for the longest substring of 1s.

```
egen history = concat(move*) 

gen max = 0 
quietly forval j = 1/6 { 
    replace max = `j' if strpos(history, substr("111111", 1, `j')) 
}
```

If the number is much more than 6, use something like

```
 local lookfor : di _dup(42) "1" 
 quietly forval j = 1/42 { 
     replace max = `j' if strpos(history, substr("`lookfor'", 1, `j')) 
 }
```

Compare also http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0056

**Strategic answer**

Storing a sequence rowwise is working against the grain so far as Stata is concerned. Much more flexibility is available if you `reshape long` and `tsset` your data as panel data. Note that the code here uses `tsspell` which must be installed from SSC using `ssc inst tsspell`.

`tsspell` is dedicated to identifying spells or runs in which some condition remains true. Here the condition is that a variable is 1 and since the only other allowed value is 0 that is equivalent to a variable being positive. `tsspell` creates three variables, giving spell identifier, sequence within spell and whether the spell is ending. Here the maximum length of spell is just the maximum sequence number for each game.

```
. input simulation playerlist temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4 temp5 temp6 

 simulat~n  playerl~t      temp1      temp2      temp3      temp4      temp5      temp6
 1.   1   1  0  1  1  1  0  0 
 2.   1   2  1  0  0  0  1  1 
 3. end 

. reshape long temp , i(sim playerlist) j(seq) 
(note: j = 1 2 3 4 5 6)

 Data                               wide   ->   long
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Number of obs.                        2   ->      12
 Number of variables                   8   ->       4
 j variable (6 values)                     ->   seq
 xij variables:
                   temp1 temp2 ... temp6   ->   temp
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. egen id = group(sim playerlist) 

. tsset id seq 
   panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
    time variable:  seq, 1 to 6
            delta:  1 unit

. tsspell, p(temp) 

. egen max = max(_seq), by(id) 

. l

      +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
      | simula~n   player~t   seq   temp   id   _seq   _spell   _end   max |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
   1. |        1          1     1      0    1      0        0      0     3 |
   2. |        1          1     2      1    1      1        1      0     3 |
   3. |        1          1     3      1    1      2        1      0     3 |
   4. |        1          1     4      1    1      3        1      1     3 |
   5. |        1          1     5      0    1      0        0      0     3 |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
   6. |        1          1     6      0    1      0        0      0     3 |
   7. |        1          2     1      1    2      1        1      1     2 |
   8. |        1          2     2      0    2      0        0      0     2 |
   9. |        1          2     3      0    2      0        0      0     2 |
  10. |        1          2     4      0    2      0        0      0     2 |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
  11. |        1          2     5      1    2      1        2      0     2 |
  12. |        1          2     6      1    2      2        2      1     2 |
      +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```