# Creating a loop to sort data together

Tags: loops, stata

I have the following data:

```
 id  date   day_1...day_6...day_20   port_ent  port_day_1...port_day_6...port_day_20
  1  1/1/00     2      4       6           1       2          4              6
  2  1/6/00     1      2       5           6       .          2              5
  3  1/16/00    3      2       1          16       .          .              1
  4  1/20/00    6      3       2          20       .          .              2
```

I am trying to create the variables `port_day_i`.

`day_i`: given the `date` how many widgets were sold in the i *th* day (when `i` = 1 this is the same day as `date`)

`port_ent`: a standardized date system that uses `id = 1` as `port_day_1`

`port_day_i`: on that portfolio day what were the sales from each individual

The day you enter the portfolio the data from your `day_1` is used and then the next day your `day_2` etc.

I thought this loop would work but it doesn't:

```
forval j = 2/100 { 
local i = `j' - port_ent + 1
    gen port_day_`j' = .
    replace port_day_`j' = day_`i' if `i' > 0
}
```

This code would get me part way there but obviously this would be very cumbersome and I have over 1000 days of data

```
gen port_day_1 = .
replace port_day_1 = day_1 if port_ent == 1

gen port_day_2 = .
replace port_day_2 = day_2 if port_ent == 1
replace port_day_2 = day_1 if port_ent == 2

gen port_day_3 = .
replace port_day_3 = day_3 if port_ent == 1
replace port_day_3 = day_2 if port_ent == 2
replace port_day_3 = day_1 if port_ent == 3

gen port_day_4 = .
replace port_day_4 = day_4 if port_ent == 1
replace port_day_4 = day_3 if port_ent == 2
replace port_day_4 = day_2 if port_ent == 3
replace port_day_4 = day_1 if port_ent == 4

gen port_day_5 = .
replace port_day_5 = day_5 if port_ent == 1
replace port_day_5 = day_4 if port_ent == 2
replace port_day_5 = day_3 if port_ent == 3
replace port_day_5 = day_2 if port_ent == 4
replace port_day_5 = day_1 if port_ent == 5

gen port_day_6 = .
replace port_day_6 = day_6 if port_ent == 1
replace port_day_6 = day_5 if port_ent == 2
replace port_day_6 = day_4 if port_ent == 3
replace port_day_6 = day_3 if port_ent == 4
replace port_day_6 = day_2 if port_ent == 5
replace port_day_6 = day_1 if port_ent == 6
```

Comment: If you put a `display` one line below your `local i` (and comment out everything else), you'll see that `i=j` in all rounds of your loop. Try with `display "i = " \`i' ", j = " \`j'` and see for yourself. I suppose that is unintended. By the wording of the problem, I can't actually understand what you seek. Maybe you don't even need the loop.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I am trying to create the `port_day_i` columns. I am assuming my misspecification of `i` is my main issue, but I do not know how to fix it. I am open to a non-loop answer,  but I am not sure that would work.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer If this helps: the initial `i` should be unique to the record and should then increase by one at every iteration for each record (from this initial `i`).

Comment: I do understand that you're trying to create those variables. Please describe why `port_day_j` takes the values it takes for some `id`s (e.g. `id = 1` and 2).

Comment: For `id=2`, does `port_day_6` take on the value of `1` because `port_ent = 6` and `1` is the value of `day_1`? If so, then for the same `id`, I think `port_day_20` (14 days after day 6) does not necessarily take on the value of `5`. The value taken by `port_day_20` should be that of `day_15` (14 days after day 1) which does not appear in your example database.

Comment: `port_day_6` should be `2`. @RobertoFerrer Yes, that was an error, now fixed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I also added code that gives the wanted result but would be too cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work. I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind your question. I suspect it has a bug but try it. I had to change some variable names and invent some data in order to better understand. At the end, my variable `sales_i` is your `day_i` and my `port_sales_j` is your `port_day_j`.

```
clear all
set more off

input id  str15 date day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 port_ent
  1  "1/1/00"     2      4       6    9    3   21   1 
  2  "1/3/00"     1      1       5    2    4   6   3   
  3  "1/6/00"     1      2       5    1    8   76   6
end

list

reshape long day_, i(id) j(day)
rename day_ sales
list, sepby(id)

sort id day
gen port_sales = .
by id: replace port_sales = sales[_n -(port_ent - 1)] if port_ent <= day
list, sepby(id)

reshape wide port_sales sales, i(id) j(day)
list id port_ent sales* 
list id port_ent port_sales*
```

Comment: @RobertFerrer The data are already long. The logic is simple, though I am not conveying it well. I have sales data from all of these divisions (`id`), which never repeat by day. The sales data starts on a `date`. I want to create a cumulative of sales by day. So once a new division's data starts it gets added by `day` to the other divisions that are in the timeframe.

Comment: I `reshape long` because, in my view, it is easier to manipulate that way. At the end, it is taken back to its original format. Like I said, this code seems to work. Using the input data in my answer, this code gives the same results as the long piece of code in the original post.

Comment: The objection to or suspicion about `reshape` here is groundless, as in your reaction to my suggestions. Even if you think of your data as "long", making it "long long" is one standard technique. See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/ for one worked example in context.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your `local` is not and cannot be vectorised, which is what you seem to be hoping or assuming. Thus your local macro

```
local i = `j' - port_ent + 1
```

will be interpreted as the constant resulting from evaluation of

```
local i = `j' - port_ent[1] + 1
```

in every observation.

A bigger problem is that your data structure is not fit for purpose. You have panel data that run across rows, so your variables are transposed.

This gives, I think, the essence of what you ask for, but you should consider whether the final `reshape wide` is necessary. It depends partly on what else you want to do, but for most likely panel manipulations, this data structure is better left as long.

```
clear 
input id    day_1   day_6 day_20   port_ent  
1      2      4       6           1   
2      1      2       5           6   
3      3      2       1          16   
4      6      3       2          20   
end 
reshape long day_ , i(id) 
gen day2 = day_ + port_ent - 1
rename day_ port_day
reshape wide port_day , i(id _j) j(day2)
```

Comment: This is not panel data. No `id` will show up more than one time. I understand that it cannot be vectorised but is there a way to create the `port_day_i` without the reshape? If not, the reshape doesn't seem to work without defining `j()` no?

Comment: I also added code that gives the wanted result but would be too cumbersome

Comment: You can object to the terminology "panel data" if you like but (1) you want to work rowwise, which is against the grain in Stata terms (2) you don't explain what is wrong with my solution. Wanting to loop here is distinctly perverse when Stata offers a more powerful tool that does it for you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576167/stata-maximum-number-of-consecutive-occurrences-of-the-same-value-across-variab
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230138/stata-counting-number-of-consecutive-occurrences-of-a-pre-defined-length for threads in which the OP realised eventually that `reshape` was a really good idea.

Comment: On `reshape` without `j()`: You can't `reshape` here without telling Stata what defines rows and columns to be combined. How could it be otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves a loop and is closer in form to your original attempt:

```
clear all
set more off

input id day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 port_ent
  1   2      4       6    9    3   21   1 
  2   1      1       5    2    4   6   3   
  3   1      2       5    1    8   76   6
end

forval i = 1/6 { 
    generate port_day_`i' = .

    local j = 1
    while `j' <= `i' {
        replace port_day_`i' = day_`j' if port_ent == `i' - `j' + 1
        local j = `j' + 1
    }
}

list id port_ent day* 
list id port_ent port_day*
```

Comment: The inner loop can be rewritten using `forval` too: the initialisation of `j` and its incrementation then drop out.